# UITableView cells overlap search bar view set as searchController for NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController configured as searchController for navigation bar. I have following setup.

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = LocalisedStrings.searchChannels
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

I have a UITableView as child view for the ViewController's view as follows:

```
func setupView() {
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    view.backgroundColor = secondarySurfaceColor
    view.addSubview(channelsTV)
    view.addSubview(emptyView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        channelsTV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        channelsTV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        channelsTV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        channelsTV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        
        emptyView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        emptyViewCenterYAnchorConstraint,
    ])
}
```

I am facing the following issue of UITableView items visible under the search controller for minor scrolls and is normal during normal up/down scroll sling.

[image]

Desired behavior is that the tableView cells should not overlap the Search Bar and Navigation bar. But the navigation bar should collapse from large title to small title when tableView is scrolled. Is there any way? Help on this is much-appreciated thanks in advance. Please comment if you'd need some more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this trick:

```
view.addSubview(UIView()) // To prevent the large tile nav bar from collapsing
```

I ignore the reason but this breaks the link between your the UIScrollView and the nav bar... This probably solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, it will cut the link between ScrollView and Navigation bar. But it disables the transition of the navigation bar from the large title to the small title while scrolling tableView, which is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinning the `UITableView` to the superView.topAnchor, not the safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor